# inputing a pandas dataframe matching two columns from two dataframes

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `C` and another dataframe `S`.  I want to change the values in one of the column of `C` if two columns in `C` and `S` have same values.

Please consider the example given below,

```
C.head(3)
   id1     id2  title   val
0   1      0     'abc'   0
1   2      0     'bcd'   0
2   3      0     'efg'   0

S.head(3)
   id1    id2
0   1      1
1   3      0
```

I want to assign the value of 1 to the column 'val' in C corresponding only to the rows where C.id1 = S.id1 and C.id2 = S.id2

The combination of (C.id1, C.id2) and (S.id1, S.id2) is unique in respective tables

In the above case, I want the result as

```
C.head(3)
   id1     id2  title  val
0   1      0    'abc'   0
1   2      0    'bcd'   0
2   3      0    'efg'   1
```

as only in the third row of `C`, it matches with one of the rows of `S` for the columns `id1` and `id2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and parameter `indicator`, last convert boolen mask to `0` and `1`:

```
#if same columns for join in both df parameter on is possible omit
df = C.merge(S, indicator=True, how='left')
#if multiple same columns in both df
#df = C.merge(S, indicator=True, how='left', on=['id1', 'id2'])
df['val'] = (df['_merge'] == 'both').astype(int)
df = df.drop('_merge', axis=1)
print (df)
   id1  id2  val
0    1    0    0
1    2    0    0
2    3    0    1
```

Solutiion working nice with new data:

```
df = C.merge(S, indicator=True, how='left')
#if multiple same columns in both df
#df = C.merge(S, indicator=True, how='left', on=['id1', 'id2'])
df['val'] = (df['_merge'] == 'both').astype(int)
df = df.drop('_merge', axis=1)
print (df)
   id1  id2 title  val
0    1    0   abc    0
1    2    0   bcd    0
2    3    0   efg    1
```

Comment: I edited a question to indicate the fact that `C` will contain extra columns which are not in `S`